# problem in executing flutter clean in windows 11

Tags: flutter, windows

i have a problem when executing the command 'flutter clean'

`Deleting build...                                                    3ms Flutter failed to delete a directory at "build". The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory. Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.`

i changed my computer and downloaded the project folder from Google Drive, i had windows 10 and now I have windows 11.

already tried:

- deactivate and delete the antivirus
- added the folders in Windows Defender exclusions (c:/Flutter and project folder)
- deactivated the Windows Defender protection
- changed the location of project folder

but nothing solved, i am admin user and i have permission on all folders